# Using FactoryBean and DisposableBean with Spring's Java Config

Tags: java, spring, config

The [ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean.html) is a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) implementing [DisposableBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html). When being used in Spring's XML bean definition like this

```xml
<bean id="executorService" 
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean"/>
```

the created bean will be an instance of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and ensures `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean#destroy()` is called, once the Spring Application Context is shut down.

Is it possible to configure such a bean with a Spring 3's [@Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this approach the most elegant:

```
@Configuration
public class Cfg {

    public ExecutorService executorService() {
        return executorServiceFactoryBean().getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean executorServiceFactoryBean() {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

Notice that `executorService()` is **not** annotated with `@Bean` - but you can still call it from other `@Bean`-methods requiring `ExecutorService`. Since `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` is annotated with `@Bean`, Spring will automatically manage its lifecycle (detect `DisposableBean`, etc.)